# Oracle trigger create with case statement

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I've got a problem with creating trigger in oracle, I have a table "stock". And I have fields "xxx"  ,"yyy" and "zzz". I'd like to make a trigger which can fill the another field on this "stock" table just after insert or update. I've tired something like that but I couldn't.

```
 create or replace 
Trigger Connector_Stock_Trg 
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF xxx,yyy,zzz ON STOCK
For Each Row 
Declare 
L_Temp VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
L_Temp := Case  
         When Xxx Is Not Null Then Xxx
         When yyy Is Not Null And zzz Is Not Null Then yyy||'_'||zzz
         When Yyy Is Null And zzz Is Not Null Then zzz
         WHEN zzz IS NULL AND yyy IS NOT NULL THEN yyy
   END;

   Update Stock 
   SET CONNECTOR=L_Temp;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to update the table `STOCK` but you just need to assign an expression to `:NEW.CONNECTOR` as following.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CONNECTOR_STOCK_TRG BEFORE
    INSERT OR UPDATE OF XXX, YYY, ZZZ ON STOCK
    FOR EACH ROW
--DECLARE
--    L_TEMP   VARCHAR2(64);
BEGIN
    :NEW.CONNECTOR := -- USE :NEW
        CASE
            WHEN :NEW.XXX IS NOT NULL THEN :NEW.XXX
            WHEN :NEW.YYY IS NOT NULL AND :NEW.ZZZ IS NOT NULL THEN :NEW.YYY
                                                          || '_'
                                                          || :NEW.ZZZ
            WHEN :NEW.YYY IS NULL AND :NEW.ZZZ IS NOT NULL THEN :NEW.ZZZ
            WHEN :NEW.ZZZ IS NULL AND :NEW.YYY IS NOT NULL THEN :NEW.YYY
        END;

--    UPDATE STOCK
--    SET
--        CONNECTOR = L_TEMP;

END;
/
```

Note: You can use the `Virtual Columns` concept in the Oracle for such requirements. [see this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

Cheers!!

Comment: I've got error:
Error(8,18): PLS-00201: 'xxx' identifier must be declared.
Error(6,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Comment: "New trigger variables can only be changed in before row insert or update triggers.". But I've changed trigger type and it compiled. Thanks for everything!